# "Undefined symbols for architecture i386" error of linking .a library for objective c++

Tags: compiler-construction, hyperlink, g++, llvm

I imported a library file (.a) compiled by g++ in ubuntu environment with arm flags.
I also tried compiler llvm. I created a objective c++ project and want to use this library.
I used the xcode compiling option "compiled as objective c++"
I got the link errors below. Any suggestion is welcome.
＝＝＝＝＝＝

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "xxxClass::yyyFunc(int, char*, char*, int&, float*)", referenced from:aaa.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: How is the linking step done? Order of arguments to linker is very important!!!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to link a library compiled for ARM on Linux in Xcode? Sounds pretty risky; I'm not sure they even use the same .o formats. In any case, the error you're getting is because you're linking for x86 (either for the host or for the iPhone simulator), not ARM.

Comment: smparkes, the library(.a file) is compiled in linux(ubuntu, intel 686) with the option -march i386, the xcode and ios simulator is running on apple machine(i386), the error occurs when linking the library in xcode project. I get the same error as I compiled the library with g++ option "arm".

Comment: Yeah, either this is never going to work or I'm really missing something. The object format on Linux is ELF. On OS X, it's Mach-O.

Comment: If you are taking it from Linux, its probably open source. Just compile it on your Mac OS X. That is the best way to get around the difference in object format.